# i am trying to show my posts title on show page but it shows this error again and again . i am beginner in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

**I made a controller and model for post and not able to show my post's 
title on the show page but repeatedly i am getting the same error **

```
my posts_controller code :


class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index

    end

    def new 


    end
    def create
    #render plain: params[:post][:body].inspect
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
        redirect_to posts_path
    else
        render "new"
    end
    end
   def show
    @post= Post.find(:id=>params[:id])
    # @article = "prateek"
   end
   private
   def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title,:body)

   end
end
```

**my show.html.erb file :**

```
<h1><%= @post.title %></h1>
```

**my post.rb file:**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
end


**I expect the result but I didn't get anything right
 error = NoMethodError in Posts#show
    undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass**
```

Comment: Can you post the stack error present in console?

Comment: could you post your code in github

Comment: i got my title when to posts/10 or posts/id  but when i go through submitting the button i got routes error like no routes [posts/new]

Answer (score 2):

You're passing an hash to `find`, while you're suppose to pass just the id.

```
@post= Post.find(params[:id])
```

or use `find_by` if you want to pass an hash

```
@post= Post.find_by(:id => params[:id])
```

Comment: Do you have any before_action?

Comment: Because what's strange you should get an error before that one of the title

Comment: Is that exactly the code you have? Because it seems you're accessing title inside your action and that's not what we see

Comment: i dont have any before_action and yes this is only my code

Comment: In this case you should get an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error unless you're catching this kind of errors somewhere else

Comment: Try to get the `id` present in URL and execute `Post.find` inside `rails console`

Comment: can you please provide me the whole code like everything models and controllers i'll try this same thing by making new project

Comment: wender freese sorry i didnt get you

Comment: On your console run `rails console` and write there `Post.find(here the id present in your #show url)`

Comment: #<Post id: 8, title: "pratik", body: "vyas", created_at: "2019-06-06 02:21:25", updated_at: "2019-06-06 02:21:25">
irb(main):002:0> i got this

Comment: 10/10 for persistence